# javascript parse string and check with conditional logic

Tags: javascript

If I have data that looks like this

```
const reqObjects = {
    "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
    "VAV2": "read 12345:3 analogInput 1",
    "VAV3": "read 12345:4 analogInput 1",
    "VAV4": "read 12345:5 analogInput 2",
    "VAV5": "read 12345:6 analogInput 1",
    "VAV6": "read 12345:7 analogInput 2",
    "VAV7": "read 12345:8 analogInput 1",
    "VAV8": "read 12345:9 analogInput 1",
    "VAV9": "read 12345:10 analogInput 2",
    "VAV10": "read 12345:11 analogInput 1"
  }
```

How could I loop through this by feeding this data into a function, parse keys into string values, and use conditional logic to verify each of key values seem appropriate?

Dumbing this down a little bit for one string:

`var myVar = "read 12345:2 analogInput 2";`

I can split this into pieces:

`var myVarParts = myVar.split(" ");`

And assign variables to each piece:

```
requestType = myVarParts[0];
console.log(requestType)

deviceAddress = myVarParts[1];
console.log(deviceAddress)

pointType = myVarParts[2];
console.log(pointType)

pointAddress = myVarParts[3];
console.log(pointAddress)
```

Trying to make up some conditional logic if the `requestType` is good if its a `read, write, release`:

```
if(requestType === "read"){
    console.log("Good on read");
  }else if(requestType === "write"){
    console.log("Good on write");
  }else if(requestType === "release"){
    console.log("Good on release");
  }else{
    console.log("BAD requestType");
  }
```

The `pointType` is good if its a `analogInput, analogValue, binaryValue, binaryInput`.

Could someone give me a tip on what a Boolean JavaScript function would look like that could loop through this data and verify the keys look OK?

```
const reqObjects = {
    "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
    "VAV2": "read 12345:3 analogInput 1",
    "VAV3": "read 12345:4 analogInput 1",
    "VAV4": "read 12345:5 analogInput 2",
    "VAV5": "read 12345:6 analogInput 1",
    "VAV6": "read 12345:7 analogInput 2",
    "VAV7": "read 12345:8 analogInput 1",
    "VAV8": "read 12345:9 analogInput 1",
    "VAV9": "read 12345:10 analogInput 2",
    "VAV10": "read 12345:11 analogInput 1"
  }
```

Thank you I am trying to learn JavaScript.

Comment: What's the specific problem? There are a number of ways an object can be iterated over, like getting `Object.keys(theObject)` or using `for-in`, then calling the validation function for each entry at that key. If you don't care about the keys you can get `Object.values(theObject)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), get the list of values from the object.
- Using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), iterate over the above to validate each item, you can modify the validation helpers if needed.

```js
const reqObjects = {
  "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV2": "read 12345:3 analogInput 1",
  "VAV3": "read 12345:4 analogInput 1",
  "VAV4": "read 12345:5 analogInput 2",
  "VAV5": "read 12345:6 analogInput 1",
  "VAV6": "read 12345:7 analogInput 2",
  "VAV7": "read 12345:8 analogInput 1",
  "VAV8": "read 12345:9 analogInput 1",
  "VAV9": "read 12345:10 analogInput 2",
  "VAV10": "read 12345:11 analogInput 1"
};

const validateRequestType = type => 
  ['read', 'write', 'release'].includes(type);
const validatePointType = type => 
  ['analogInput', 'analogValue', 'binaryValue', 'binaryInput'].includes(type);
const validate = str => {
  const [requestType, deviceAddress, pointType, pointAddress] = str.split(' ');
  return validateRequestType(requestType) && validatePointType(pointType);
} 
const valid = Object.values(reqObjects).every(validate);

console.log(valid);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regex `^(read|write|release)\s(\d+:\d+)\s(analog|binary)(Input|Value)\s\d$` to match the pattern.

---

- `(read|write|release)` are the options for the request type
- `(\d+:\d+)` makes sure the device address is made up of numbers separated by a colon
- `(analog|binary)(Input|Value)` are the options for the point type
- `\d` matches the single digit at the end

---

You can use `Object.values` and run `<Array>.every` to loop through the values and make sure they all match the pattern.

```js
const regex = /^(read|write|release)\s(\d+:\d+)\s(analog|binary)(Input|Value)\s\d$/;

const reqObjects = {
  "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV2": "read 12345:3 analogInput 1",
  "VAV3": "read 12345:4 analogInput 1",
  "VAV4": "read 12345:5 analogInput 2",
  "VAV5": "read 12345:6 analogInput 1",
  "VAV6": "read 12345:7 analogInput 2",
  "VAV7": "read 12345:8 analogInput 1",
  "VAV8": "read 12345:9 analogInput 1",
  "VAV9": "read 12345:10 analogInput 2",
  "VAV10": "read 12345:11 analogInput 1"
}

console.log(Object.values(reqObjects).every(val => val.match(regex)))
```